# Flutter - Automatically log-in in WebView when already logged-in in app with WordPress backend

Tags: wordpress, flutter, webview

Is there a way to automatically log-in in WebView when already logged-in in app? I'm using `webview_flutter`.
I tried this one but it didn't worked

```
WebView(
      // initialUrl: widget.url,
      javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
      onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
        _controller.complete(webViewController);
        webViewController.loadUrl(
          'https://example.com',
          headers: {"Authorization" : "Bearer $token"},
        );
      },
    ),
```

Comment: Do you van the value in `$token` to be added to the requests made from the WebVew to some remote endpoint?

Comment: @PeterKoltai the value is added in token

Comment: But how do you have to use this token in the webview? For example, does the website loading the the webview issue a HTTP POST request which must contain the token in some form?